# Static HTML, CSS, and JS to backend admin access

Tags: php, html, css, dynamic, admin

I have this static html, CSS, and JS website with a little bit of Jquery as well and I need to be able to add a backend way for other admins(ones with no development knowledge) to just login into the website and then be able to click and edit sections or click and change pictures with ones of there own. Basically I have made this whole website for a company but I do not have the time to constantly update it with there information. I need a simple way for them to be able to just login, click, and update on their own. Oh and it is being hosted by 1and1.com Thanks for the help.

It doesn't have to be dynamic I just need to find a a simple backend way for the admins to update the content and images without having to code or use dreamweaver, etc...

Comment: So you think that others can code that for you, while you sit back and relax?

Comment: Building this, basically a CMS-system, is sooo 1990. It is the top of inefficient, nowhere near sustainable, and at times endless and dangerous considering the need for security update. Things like that end up a one-man job, and rarely can others sensibly take over. If it is as simple as you say; try wordpress. It might take a little time for you to learn a CMS system, but your users will thank you, it will be less work and hassle for you, and that time is quickly saved.

Answer (score 4):

What your looking for is a Content Management System (CMS). There are plenty out there and you can just google for "basic php cms" and should find a solution.

Comment: Caelea, no I don't want others to code for me what are you even talking about? I coded the webpage myself I'm wondering how I can set it up for non-coders to update on their own...But anyway thank you Brian, I was just looking for a way to go about implementing this feature. I will look into CMS